Paste Excel Formula Columns as Values using Python
I have one excel workbook containing two sheets. Sheet2 contains whole Dump while Sheet1 has formulas which fetches certain data from Sheet2.
So, I want to remove formulas from Sheet1, so that I can do rest of the modifications. But it's not working.
There's one more issue that my table header starts from row 4.
import openpyxl

# Load the workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

# Select the worksheet
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# Iterate over cells with formulas
for row in ws.iter_rows():
     for cell in row:
    if cell.data_type == 'f':  # 'f' stands for formula
        cell.value = cell.value  # This will replace the formula with its value
        if isinstance(cell.value, str):  # Check if the value is a string
            cell.data_type = 's'  # 's' stands for string
        else:
            cell.data_type = 'n'  # 'n' stands for number

wb.save(file_path)

I tried using Pandas and it worked but it removed all the formatting and sheet2.
Then I tried OpenPyXl but it couldn't remove the formulas.
I'm expecting same workbook with 2 sheets with same formatting as before but with no formulas.

copy, paste.special_values.

@SolarMike Using Python bro.

If you load the workbook in Openpyxl with 'data_only' set to True, then it will read the cell value not the formula for cells with formulae.

And Python cannot do a "copy" in some form? Or a paste as values? Does not sound much use then...

@moken And it will cause no difference in formatting and other sheets?

@SolarMike So, what's the other way. At last I want to sort one date column which currently I'm unable to do because of the formulas present.

If you open a workbook with Sheets that contain formulas with data only enabled wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path, data_only=True) and save the workbook, the only change will be all those cells that were formulas will now contain the value. The formula is gone, permanently, so don't save to the same file name if you want to keep the original workbook with the formulas. You can also use Xlwings or Win32com in Python to run Excel commands like copy/paste special --> values.

I suppose I should clariify in the statement; ... the only change will be all those cells that were formulas will now contain the value , if the cell has a value. A cell may have a formula but not necessarily a value especaially if Openpyxl is used to add the formula to the cell(s). Openpyxl does not use Excel and does not evaluate formulas. Therefore if you add formulas to cells with Openpyxl you would then need to open the workbook in Excel to update the values.
